# Ordering guarantee in each partition using Confluent Replicator

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

There is an requirement in our systems to maintain a proper sequence and ordering guarantee of records inside a Kafka topic partition.
As observed in our test runs, Kafka Mirror does not provide an ordering guarantee in partition. Records tend to be shuffled between source and target cluster topics.

We are planning to use Confluent Replicator for cross cluster data replication. In the test run of Confluent community edition 5.3.1, it has been observed that source and destination topic maintained the exact same partition and its respective record count. (Replicator was run on single thread configs)

But, does Replicator guarantee exact ordering of records within a partition ?
And if I increase the number of replication threads for parallelism and better throughput, does it still guarantee ordering (also in case of one thread failure) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MirrorMaker (1.0) will repartition data using the DefaultPartitioner, so the only way you'd manage to get "out of order data" is by having producers overriding their partitioner. In addition, MirrorMaker does not guarantee destination topics have the same number of partitions or configurations as the source

Replicator and MirrorMaker **2.0** (available with Kafka 2.4.0) preserve the input partition counts and topic configs. Order is guaranteed as well as any other consumer group. It might be possible records are produced more than once during delivery due to edge cases in network transmission errors, however.

Increasing connector tasks will add more consumers to the group, again, same as any other application, and input and output partitions should match

Comment: So Mirror Maker 2.0 doesn't support exactly once guarantees?

Comment: @JavaT it might... The documentation is very scarce

Comment: Does Mirror maker 2.0 take care of consumer offsets also? Like which are committed or not committed for a particular consumer group?

Comment: Thanks cricket_007. MirrorMaker 2.0  currently does not seem to be packaged with the latest confluent platform 5.3.2 version

Comment: @IshanGandhi It is not. But you can use later Apache Kafka versions with Confluent 3.2 and higher

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. one more question please. In case of Active-Passive DC replication using Replicator, how can the messages lost due to replication lag can be restored, in case the source DC1 is down ? Also does replicator provide an exact data gurantee incase of for restoration  of DC1  ?

Comment: If the source DC is down, then Replicator is not polling anything. If messages are lost from lag+expiration, they are gone forever. No tool can protect you from that